# Export billing documents to Excel

Tags: excel, sap-erp

Can anyone help me?  I have an excel worksheet with 6260 invoice numbers. I have to search in SAP ERP `VF03` transaction the billing documents, than write in the original Excel the fields "Comm./imp.code no." and the gross weight next to the invoice number.

Do you know any reports in SAP that can speed up the process or a macro in excel?

Manually it is time-wasting. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you need the list of billing documents.

SAP CODE: **VF05** - List Billing Documents

After you have downloaded this, you can then create an excel sheet and match it with your list.

Comment: If I use VF05 the system require Payer and Material. But I only know the invoice number and where we shipped to. I would like to know all the shipped product Comm./imp.code no. and the gross weight/ shipments.